# How to store output of sudo -S su -c <user> <command> to any variable

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to execute the following command but the output is not coming as required.

```
var=$(echo "<password>"|sudo -S su -l <user> -c "<command>")
```

Please help if anyone can?
Expected Result:
var=$(echo ""|sudo -S su -l -c "pwd")
echo $var /home/bhushan 
$: 
Actual Result: 
echo $var

$:

Comment: Please mention expected and actual output. What have to tried so far?

Comment: expected Result:
var=$(echo ""|sudo -S su -l -c "pwd")
echo $var
/home/bhushan
$:


Actual Result:
echo $var

$:

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround it by storing the output of the command into a file, then change its permission so that all users will see it and in a following command load it from the file:

```
sudo -S "<command> > /tmp/sudocmd.out && chmod 644 /tmp/sudocmd.out"
var=$(cat /tmp/sudocmd.out)
```

Comment: So there is no output to the command. Seems that the issue is with the command itself

Comment: So what solution did you use eventually? Mark it with the up arrow.

Comment: actually that command which I was using was problematic so change business logic and use different test conditions.But above command 
var=$(echo "<password>"|sudo -S su -l <user> -c "<command>")
is perfect and works fine...! ^

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks

```
var=`sudo -S su -l -c ""`
```

or the `$(command)` syntax

```
var=$(sudo -S su -l -c "")
```

(keep in mind though that `sudo -S su -l -c ""` doesn't output anything so `$var` will be empty)

Comment: expected Result:
var=`sudo -S su -l -c "pwd"`
echo $var
/home/bhushan/mycode
$: